# Query to solve: whatsapp group

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, for-loop, netbeans

This is the question:

> A group of friends share messages in a WhatsApp group. Since there is
>   a risk of their ideas being hacked, they form a new method of sharing
>   text messages which is confusing for the person who hacks/views those
>   messages. Now your task is to create a program for the hacker to solve
>   his issue in decoding the messages. Sample input: REAEALAL L S
>   STSTETEEEEL Output: REAL STEEL

This is what I have worked out until now:

```
import java.util.*;
class hide
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String a=sc.nextLine();
        String b=a.substring(0,2);
        int n=a.length();
        for(int i=0;i<n-2;i++)
        {
            if(a.charAt(i)!=a.charAt(i+2))
            b=b+a.charAt(i+2);
        }
        System.out.print(b.trim());
    }
}
```

But it is not passing the test cases?

Comment: Do you know which tests cases it hasn't passed? Because for case from example it works fine

Comment: even I am not able to understand the cases  ! The code gives right output still..... @Vlad

Comment: @dutaravi12345 just because a single testcase is valid it doesn´t mean it´s completly valid. But given the input inside the question i feel like the decoding should be happening in a different way.

Comment: how ?? I cannot understand ! @KevinEsche

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given how the input looks, i assume the encoding happens like this:

```
// The used length should be 3;
String encode(String input, int length) {
    String output = "";
    for(int i = 0;i<input.length();++i) {
        output += input.subSequence(i, i+length);
        if(i+length== input.length()) break;
    }
    return output;
}
```

using this code, the desired encoding would be the same as your encoded `String` which you have to decode.

Using the same mechanism, the decode could happen like this:

```
static String decode(String input, int length) {
    String output = "";
    for(int i = 0;i<input.length();i+=length) {
        output +=input.charAt(i);
        if(i+length>=input.length())
            output += input.substring(i+1);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Given a tiny program, the code could decode and encode the given `String`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "REAL STEEL";
    String encoded = encode(s1, 3);
    System.out.println("Encoded the original " + s1 + " to be " + encoded);
    System.out.println("Decoded again to: " + decode(encoded,3));
}

static String encode(String input, int length) {
    String output = "";
    for(int i = 0;i<input.length();++i) {
        output += input.subSequence(i, i+length);
        if(i+length== input.length()) break;
    }
    return output;
}

static String decode(String input, int length) {
    String output = "";
    for(int i = 0;i<input.length();i+=length) {
        output +=input.charAt(i);
        if(i+length>=input.length())
            // Whenever the end was reached, the repeating has stopped
            // Here it just adds to the end of the output what is left.
            output += input.substring(i+1);
    }
    return output;
}
```

O/P

```
Encoded the original REAL STEEL to be REAEALAL L S STSTETEEEEL
Decoded again to: REAL STEEL
```

The difference to your code is, that it doesn´t strictly use the first two characters as given for the encoding, but does rather notice when the end of the encoding was reached (and though the repitition). In this case it´l just add the missing letters to the end of the decoded output.